# Switch the case of letters

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

I'm trying the following problem:

> Define `String.prototype.toAlternatingCase` (or a similar function/method such as `to_alternating_case`/`toAlternatingCase`/`ToAlternatingCase` in your selected language; see the initial solution for details) such that each lowercase letter becomes uppercase and each uppercase letter becomes lowercase.

This is what I've tried so far but I don't really know why it's not working. Please, take into account that I've just started coding so I might be making very basic mistakes:

```
def to_alternating_case(string):
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) in range(97, 123):
            string.replace(char, string.upper())
        elif ord(char) in range (65,91):
            string.replace(char, string.lower())
        elif ord(char) in range (32, 48):
            continue
        else:
            return '//Non-alphabetical characters are unaffected'
    return string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is strings are immutable.

So this line returns a new string rather than replacing a character in string.

```
string.replace(char, string.upper())
```

**Fixed Posted Code**

```
def to_alternating_case(string):
    result = ""
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) in range(97, 123):
            result += char.replace(char, char.upper())  # replace invidivual character
        elif ord(char) in range (65,91):
            result += char.replace(char, char.lower())  # replace invidivual character
        else:                                          # characaters outside [a-zA-Z] unchanged
            result += char
    return result

print(to_alternating_case("heLLo"))  # Outputs "HEllO"
```

**Code Rewrite**

Simpler method.

```
def to_alternating_case(string):
    return ''.join(c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower() for c in string)

print(to_alternating_case("heLLo"))  # Outputs "HEllO"
```